# Acces environment.js from Ember addon index.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am building a Ember addon and I will like to know if there is a way to access the config/environment.js file from the root index.js. Basically I would like have the same config value used from the root index.js and a component.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`const config = this.project.config()`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `require` it:

```
// index.js
var environment = 'production'; // optional
var ENV = require('config/environment')(environment);
console.log(ENV.baseURL);
```